# Using PHP to Query Fields of a DB Table for Substrings

Tags: php, database, html, mysqli

I am trying to write some PHP code that will query the last 10 rows of a database table (made up of three fields) and search for any instance of a string/substring "word" and count them -- including multiple times in single cell. Here is what I have so far:

```
    $query = "SELECT * from my_table WHERE column1 LIKE '%word%'
                UNION ALL SELECT * from my_table WHERE column2 LIKE '%word%'";

    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);

    $i = 0;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $i++;
    }
    echo "<i>This table contains [" . $i . "] instances of the string \"word\".</i>";

    mysqli_free_result($result);
    mysqli_close($mysqli);
```

The problem I am running into is:

1. This is polling my entire database, not just the last 10 rows. If I include "ORDER BY PID DESC LIMIT 10" the query no longer seems to work with WHERE and LIKE.
2. It does not catch multiple instances of the string in a single cell.

I have spent hours on this - I would appreciate any advice. Thanks so much!

/**** UDPATE ****/

Here is what I ended up with. IN essence I converted my query into an array and then into a string. From there I searched for all instances of "word". Thanks everyone for the help.

```
    $query = "SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY PID DESC LIMIT 10";
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);

    $j = 0;
    $i = 'word';

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
    $intoarray = implode(",", $row);
    $j += substr_count($intoarray, $i); 
    }

    echo "<i>This table contains [" . ($j / 2) . "] instances of the string \"word\".</i>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using backtick symbol for all of name of tables and columns.  You can find `` ` ``on your US keyboard, right above your `<TAB>` key.  For example:

ORIGINAL ANSWER:

```
"SELECT * from `my_table` WHERE `column1` LIKE '%word%'"
```

EDITED as per comments to this:

```
$query = "SELECT * from `my_table` WHERE `column1` LIKE '%word%'
            UNION ALL SELECT * from `my_table` WHERE `column2` LIKE '%word%'";
```

This query runs fine on my server.

Comment: and as a friendly tip - try avoid mysql as it's being phased out and will be depreciated - use PDO.  It'll save you from hassles.

Comment: added them. Didn't seem to make any difference in the result. I tried to add the statement ORDER BY PID DESC LIMIT 10 after I add them and no change. #fustrated!

Comment: What is PID that you defined in your SQL?  Maybe this will do: `SELECT * FROM \`members\` WHERE \`column1\` LIKE '%word%' ORDER BY \`PID\` DESC LIMIT 10 `

Comment: Faron - let me clarify. It works, however it seems to search the entire table; I only want it to look at the last 10 rows. This is why I'm trying to incorporate DESC LIMIT 10 - but when included in the select statement it doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

I created following query for my table and it works fine

```
(select * from eas_appliciant
where appliciant_id = '6'
order by appliciant_id limit 0,1)
union all
(select * from eas_appliciant
where appliciant_id = '7'
order by appliciant_id limit 0,1)
```

you can create also follow

```
(   SELECT column1 as selected_column from my_table 
    WHERE column1 LIKE '%word%' 
    ORDER BY PID DESC LIMIT 0,10 )
UNION ALL
(   SELECT colum2 as selected_column from my_table 
    WHERE column2 LIKE '%word%' 
    ORDER BY PID DESC LIMIT 0,10)
```

I do not know why it is not working for you

Comment: Hassan - would I write that like $query = "(...) UNION ALL (...)"?

Comment: yes. whole above query in the string including brackets

Comment: Got it. However the query still appears to search beyond the last 10 rows - basically the entire table. is my while() perhaps the issue?

Comment: than it is not confusing because we query table two time with order by pid desc limit 0.10 and union them so there should not order rows included ? if you are expecting maximum 10 rows than there could be more than 10 rows. single row can appear twice if it meets criteria for both column1 and column2